# Custom Plugin transitive Dependency resolution in BuildConfig.groovy Grails 2.2.3

Tags: grails, dependencies, ivy, grails-plugin, grails-2.2

## tl;dr version

Dependencies of my custom grails plugin weren't getting inherited and resolved by projects I installed the plugin to.

- Install the latest version of the release plugin to your plugin (fixes the issue for jar dependencies)
- Clear out any references to plugins that might exist in your BuildConfig.groovy file (fixes the issue for plugin dependencies)
- `grails maven-install` to make the plugin available in the mavenLocal() source

## Long version

So, I've been trying to create a custom grails plugin for internal use at my University.

I'd really like it if putting the plugin in your BuildConfig.groovy file's plugins closure would automatically install not just the plugin, but all the dependencies defined for the plugin in its BuildConfig.groovy file (or, after packaging, its dependencies.groovy file).

Looking at [the instructions](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.3/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories), I have setup the BuildConfig.groovy file for my project with this in the repositories closure:

```
flatDir name:'my-plugin', dirs:'/Users/me/workspace-ggts/myplugin'
```

Then added this to the plugins closure:

```
compile(":grails-my-plugin:0.1")
```

That does install the plugin correctly, but it doesn't resolve any of the plugin's dependencies or needed plugins. Here's the three main closures in the plugin's BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo "http://www.mygrid.org.uk/maven/repository"
    def jbossResolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()
    jbossResolver.addArtifactPattern("https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/com/sun/media/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]")
    jbossResolver.addArtifactPattern("https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/javax/media/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]")
    resolver jbossResolver
}
dependencies {

    compile (
        [group:'javax.media', name:'jai-core', version:'1.1.3'],
        [group:'com.sun.media', name:'jai-codec', version:'1.1.3']
        )
    compile "net.java.dev.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core-standalone:1.2-pre-dr-b04-2013-04-23" //this jar comes from the mygrid mavenRepo
}

plugins {
    build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
          ":release:1.0.0") {
        export = false
    }
    compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
    compile ":wslite:0.7.2.0"
}
```

If I run the plugin using `grails run-app`, it resolves all of those dependencies just fine.  It's only when the plugin is installed to a project that automatic dependency resolution fails.

I've tried [making the plugin a maven artifact, and copying it to my local repository](http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/02/13/grails-2-2-publishing-your-plugins-as-maven-artifacts-to-resolve-dependency-resolution-issues/). In those cases, I removed the `flatDir` line from the `repositories` closure and replaced it with mavenLocal(). Again, the plugin itself installs, but none of the specified dependencies do.

I've tried setting legacyResolve in BuildConfig.groovy to true, but this also fails to install either the jars or the needed plugins (like wslite).

I even tried manually specifying `compile(":grails-my-plugin:0.1") {transitive: true}`, but it still won't resolve the plugins.

Between all of the above attempts I've uninstalled my plugin, run `grails clean` on the project, deleted the contents of the ~/.grails/2.2.3/cached-installed-plugins/ directory, and poured libation while intoning the holy name of Burt Beckwith, but I *still* can't get transitive resolution.

One other noteworthy thing: I've run a dependency-report on the project. It lists my plugin among the dependencies, but the report says that the plugin itself has no dependencies.

I also ran refresh-dependencies myAppDeps.xml in order to get a dependency report. It contains none of the plugin's dependencies that aren't also dependencies of a vanilla grails project.

Grails plugins in the public repositories get their dependencies resolved automagically (try putting spring-security-ldap in your BuildConfig.groovy file as an example, and spring-security-core will install). Does transitive resolution simply not work for local plugins? Are there any ways to make it work, like tacking something into _Install.groovy?

### Update

So, I tried dmahapatro's suggestion. That *did* work for getting the jars on which myPlugin depends installed in the project; thus, the project compiles and the dependency report contains the needed jars. However, the *plugins* that myPlugin depends on are still not getting installed into the projects that I install myPlugin too. When I try to run the app after a successful compilation, I get this error:

```
| Error Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [myPlugin]
- Plugin: myPlugin
   - Dependencies:
       - springSecurityCore (Required: 1.2 > *, Found: 1.2.7.3) 
       - jquery (Required: 1.7 > *, Found: 1.8.3) 
       ! wslite (Required: 0.7.2 > *, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
```

### Further Update

So, I decided to try to isolate the problem. I created a fresh plugin (`grails create-plugin transitiveDep`), and a fresh project (`grails create-app horseradish`). I copied the relevant portions of BuildConfig.groovy from my working projects into each, changing the plugin dependency from my-plugin to transitive-dep.

Lo and behold, horseradish successfully installed all the needed dependencies (wslite, springSecurityCore). It even asked if I wanted to install the older version of jQuery.

So, nothing is wrong with my environment. I suspect at this point that something else is wrong with the plugin's configuration. It was originally written in Grails 2.0.1, then upgraded to 2.2.3. I've also tried installing it into a fresh app, just like I did my transitive-dep plugin, but with it still failed to resolve plugin dependencies. I'll post an update when I've figured out exactly where the issue is.

### Final Update

So, the thing keeping the *plugins* from installing was that myPlugin referenced them in the application.properties file *as well as* BuildConfig.groovy. If I deleted the references to them there before packaging, the plugin installed just fine.

I also noticed that I still had the old Grails version (2.0) in myPluginGrailsPlugin.groovy file, as well as a dependsOn map that doesn't seem to be needed anymore. I removed/altered those lines, but it wasn't until clearing out the old references in application.properties that things really started working.

Notably, I also had to clear out my ~/.grails/2.2.3, ~/.grails/ivy-cache folders, and ~/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/ directories after making changes to myPlugin, or my projects would still try to install the old versions. I got so tired of doing that, I made a shell script to do it:

```
cd ~/.grails/2.2.3/
rm -r *
cd ~/.grails/ivy-cache/
rm -r *
cd ~/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/
rm -r *
```

Comment: *poured libation while intoning the holy name* - liked it. :)

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have used Pabst...

Comment: Do you have your app and the plugin running in same machine?

Comment: Yes, they're on the same machine.

Comment: An off-topic fair warning to anyone else who has read this far: the jai dependencies will only resolve on a second run of refresh-dependencies. Not sure why. Disabling checksum checking with checksums false doesn't fix it. Ah well. That's another question for another day.

Comment: Does anyone have this working with 2.3? I'm still not getting inherited dependencies in my main app. I started with a barebones plugin; added compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3" to BuildConfig; grails compile; grails maven-install. Then added my plugin to a new app but the spring-security classes aren't resolving. pom.xml of the plugin does not list spring-security. Nothing in application.properties. Any ideas?

Comment: Update to my comment above: I tried the same thing on 2.2.4 and it worked perfectly. So I guess 2.3 is not quite ready to handle that. This issue may be referring to that: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10437

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Important actions to note and rectify (w.r.t Grails 2.2.3):

- Check your `application.properties` file. **There should not be any reference to installed plugins in application.properties**. If you had been installing plugins using the `install-plugin command` (which I discourage now since it will no longer be available), they were likely be written to that file. Delete any lines referencing installed plugins before you do a `grails refresh-dependencies` and `grails maven-install`.
- Upgrade `release` plugin inside your plugin to `v2.2.1`

as below if you are using latest version of grails.

```
......
build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
          ":release:2.2.1") {
        export = false
}
.......
```

- When you do `grails maven-install` on the plugin, the resultant zip created will be named as `grails-my-plugin.zip` if the plugin project name is `MyPlugin`, but when you refer the plugin in your grails application (retrieving from .m2 local repo), you have to refer the plugin as

  `compile ':my-plugin:0.1' //instead of "grails-my-plugin"`

**Observation:**

- I was facing issues (related to svn plugin) using `release:1.0.0` (deliberately downgraded to replicate your issue) when testing so it is a better idea to upgrade to version **2.2.1** if you are using Grails **2.2.*** etc. You would not be able to use v3.0.0 unless you use Grails **2.3** as mentioned in the doc.
- It did not complain anything when I used `mygrid` repo while testing. [`http://www.mygrid.org.uk/maven/repository`]
- Once `my-plugin` was added to my application I was able to compile my app where it installed spring security core referred from `my-plugin`.
- [Dependency report](http://pbrd.co/16LUtPp) showed the transitive dependencies as well.

*Tested in Grails 2.2.3*

Comment: That did work for getting the jar files that the plugin depends on (jai-core, jai-codec, and jai-imageio-core-standalone) into the project. However, see my latest update.

Comment: @jonnybot My dependency report snapshot shows the plugins inside `my- plugin` as well.

Comment: Odd. Your myPlugin actually shows its dependencies in the report. Mine does not. http://pbrd.co/1bzf78n    
  
bdmPlugin is the actual name of my plugin. :)  
  
The jai jars just get listed separately, as independent dependencies, even though they're definitely _not_ in the project's BuildConfig.groovy.  
http://pbrd.co/1bzgfsL  
http://pbrd.co/1bzgrYY

Answer (score 0):

on the plugin project run package-plugin. it will generate the dependency file for you. Than you should not get this dependency issue.

Comment: I sincerely wish that were true, but it isn't. I've already run `grails package-plugin` and installed the resultant zip file. Even though the dependencies.groovy file contained in the zip file is correct, the dependencies don't get automatically resolved when installing the plugin into an application, or when running the application after plugin install.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue of application not detecting transitive dependencies from plugin.
My plugin's grails version was 2.3.4 and the app that used the plugin was 2.1.0.

The plugin was packaged using `grails publish-plugin` and manually uploaded to a private Maven compatible repository(Artifactory).

Grails 2.3.4 doesn't generate *dependencies.groovy* and the app didn't figure out the transitive dependencies and failed compilation.

As @rittinger mentioned in this post [custom-plugin-dependencies-groovy-is-ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257932/custom-plugin-dependencies-groovy-is-ignored) pom does the trick. When I manually uploaded the plugin.zip file to Artifactory, it generated a pom file which didn't have a `<dependencies/>` section.

But when I followed the [release plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/guide/introduction.html) instructions and uploaded the plugin to Artifactory, the generated pom file had `<dependencies/>` section. Afterwards the App didn't have any problems resolving transitive dependencies.